# Multiple update mySQL database with array?

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel

I'm using php with Laravel. I want to update my database with this array, when I excecute this query to  update my db, this db updated by 2 times.

It was like array 1, array 1 then array, 2 array 2... What I want just array 1 then array 2. So how do I solve this problem? Thanks.

```
$chcount = count($kfamily_profile['chname'])-1;

for($x=0;$x<=$chcount;$x++)
{

    $childinput[$x] = array(
        'child_name'            => $kfamily_profile['chname'][$x],
        'gender'                => $kfamily_profile['chgender'][$x],
        'child_pob'             => $kfamily_profile['chpob'][$x],
        'child_dob'             => $kfamily_profile['chdob'][$x]
    );

    DB::table('kids')
                    ->where('fathers_name','=', $fname)
                    ->where('mothers_name','=', $mname)
                    ->orderBy('child_dob','ASC')
                    ->update($childinput[$x]);

}
```

Comment: Why did you choose to format your `$kfamily_profile` array the way it is? It would be much easier to work with if it was formatted  `$kfamily_profile[$x]['chname']` instead.

Comment: Because $kfamily_profile['chname'] is one unit to get the value from input Form then [$x] define an index

Comment: Your form inputs can have name elements like `name="family[$x][chname]"`

Comment: my form inputs have an elements like this: name="chname[]". $kfamily_profile come from my controller $kfamily_profile = Input::all();